# A confusion from midterm exam's question -absolute convergent series-

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

There was a question in my exam :

> Let $x=(x_n)=(0,0,..,0,1/n^2,0,0,..)\in c_{00}$
>
> Show that $\sum_{n=1}^n x_n$ is absolute convergent but not convergent in $c_{00}$ space wrt $\|.\|_{\infty}$ norm.

The reason of my confusion can I use terms that include "$n$" in components of vectors?

I have said it is absolute convergent since

$\sup_{n\in \mathbb N}|x_n|=1/n^2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^n 1/n^2 \lt \infty$

for not being convergent I have said,

Let $S_j=(0,0,..,1/n^2)$ is partial sum of $x_n$

$S=(1/n,1/n,...,1/n)$

$\sup_{j\in \mathbb N}|S_j-S|=1/n \lt \varepsilon$

$S_j \to S$ and $S \notin c_{00} $

Thus $S_j$ sequence is not convergent in $c_{00}$

I have written more detailed in exam, I know writing is not well enough in here but I am pledge in StackExchange :)

As I said before I confused about using "$n$" in components. For writing $S$, I'm inspired from $(0,0,..,0,1/n^2,0,0,..)$.(since it has a component which has "$n$").   Is $S=(1/n,1/n,...,1/n)$ incorrect notation?

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble understanding your notation, or you seem to have calculated the partial sums wrong.

If we denote the sequence of partial sums by $(S_n)_n$ then

$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \left(1, \frac1{2^2}, \frac1{3^2}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n^2}, 0, 0, \ldots\right)$$

Now recall that convergence in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ implies coordinate-wise convergence, in the sense that if $x_n \xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|_\infty}x$ then the sequence of $i$-th coordinates of $(x_n)_n$ converges to the $i$-th coordinate of $x$, for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Hence the only possible candidate for $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$ is its coordinate-wise limit, which is

$$\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)_n = \left(1, \frac1{2^2}, \frac1{3^2}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n^2}, \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}, \ldots\right)$$

However, this is not an element of $c_{00}$ so $(S_n)_n$ cannot converge.

Comment: @esrabasar I perhaps misunderstood the problem. The sequence $(x_j)_j$ is given by $x_j = \left(0, \ldots, 0, \frac1{j^2}, 0, \ldots\right)$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. You were solving the problem as if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ was fixed and the sequence is given by $$x_j = \begin{cases}
 \left(0, \ldots, 0, \frac1{n^2}, 0, \ldots\right),  & \text{if $j = n$} \\
 \left(0, 0, \ldots\right), & \text{if $j \ne n$}
\end{cases}$$
But this would make the entire problem rather trivial since then you have a finite sum: $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j = x_n$$ This certainly converges, absolutely and otherwise.

Comment: Yes but I think it is not for $\exists N \in \mathbb N$ because otherwise the series must have been convergent but according to question it is not convergent, it is only absolutely convergent. I am in notation of question not clear enough :(

Comment: thanks for your concern :)